# Changing the desktop GUI

Tags: 14.04, gui, unity-dash

I use Ubuntu 14.04 at work. It's the first *major* use of Linux that I've had. I have gotten used to it so much that I prefer using it instead of Windows for all work, particularly in a command line; I am a software developer so perhaps this might not surprise you.

I am considering installing Ubuntu in a new personal laptop.

However, I would want to *completely remove* Dash. I am absolutely not interested in searching my computer through a GUI (I use *`find`*). I've had Ubuntu 14.04 for two years and haven't used Dash a single time. It's intrusive to my workflow. I do not want to pay the cost of a background application indexing my machine. I do not want to pay the cost of the indexed database storage on my machine.

I want, instead, a more Windows XP style prompt. It should have a hierarchy of directories which I manually created. I have that already on the filesystem, but a GUI navigation tree would be *acceptable*. However, having this menu is not as important to me as removing Dash.

Comment: Install Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu MATE will provide choices that you outlined

Comment: this is what you need!!! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z61_04FIavY